# error: parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it. kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> $completion);

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Trying to run the app and getting this error:
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> $completion);

its actually showing error under build folder which are generated files and we are not recommended to edit that file.

Below my build.gradle:

```
    plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id ("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")


}

android {
    namespace = "com.shubhamtripz.notebox"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.shubhamtripz.notebox"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.1")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48")


    val room_version = "2.5.2"

    implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2")
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2")
    kapt ("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")


    val lifecycle_version = "2.6.1"

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")


}
```

bELOW MY NoteDao.kt file:

```
package com.shubhamtripz.notebox.data.dao

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.Update
import com.shubhamtripz.notebox.data.entity.Note
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Dao
interface NoteDao {
    @Query("select * from notes ORDER BY date desc")
    fun getAllNotes(): Flow<List<Note>>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertNote(note: Note)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateNote(note: Note)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteNote(note: Note)
}
```

I tried with all latest versions of room
also tried ksp in place of kapt, can't use ksp as hilt is not suppporting ksp, so have to use kapt only.

Comment: The error is stating that the return type  `Note` should be an `Entity`  ..  Looks like you are missing `@Entity` annotation on Your Note class . Dao method can only perform provided crud actions with  an Entity Object or a collection of it as data.